# reverse words in a sentence using istringstream and istream_iterator

Tags: c++, c++11, istringstream

Trying to solve the problem using C++ constructs. Reference to each word in the sentence is taken and reversed. But the changes are not seen in the original sentence.

```
class Solution {
public:
    string reverseWords(string s) {
        istringstream ss(s);
        for(auto w = istream_iterator<string>(ss); w != istream_iterator<string>(); w++)
        {
            /* changes of the below 2 lines are not reflected in the main sentence*/
            string &str = const_cast<string&>(*w);
            reverse(str.begin(),str.end());           
        }
        reverse(s.begin(),s.end());
    return s;
    }
};
```

Comment: Using `const_cast` in such a manner is undefined behavior. That alone makes the entire program wrong. Just because you told the compiler to ignore the constness, doesn't mean the constness isn't there.

Comment: @DeiDei: how do I get the job done without making a copy of the word.

Comment: It's not worth it. Just the split the sentence into words and add them to a `std::vector`, then just `return std::string(vector.rbegin(), vector.rend());`. And you're done. Could be done with 2-3 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to use streams without copying the word as the stream would always extract the word into a separate string. In your attempt, you are also modifying such a copy, that's why you get the original string returned. I would just use iterators (this is to be taken as pseudo-code, may not compile):

```
auto last = s.begin();
auto cur = s.begin();

while (cur != s.end()) {
  if (!isalpha(*(cur++))) {
     reverse(last, cur);
     last = cur;
  }
}

reverse(last, cur);
return s;
```